# Sending a nodejs req.file to Python script

Tags: javascript, python, node.js

I've got a node server setup which accepts pdf uploads and uploads them to a hedera blockchain testnet.

```
app.post('/upload', upload.single('pdf'), function (req. res) {
    uploadToBlockchain(req.file)
    res.send('finished')
})
```

and a python script which does some processing on a file given a file buffer:

```
from Transformer import Transformer as tf

with open('file_path', 'rb') as pdf_file:
    images = pdf_file.read()

a = tf.bytes_to_hash_array(images)
print(a)
```

Is there some way to link these two up, so that I can send the PDF data I received from node(req.file) and pipe it to the python script to process and return the results? I've tried a few things with child process but haven't managed to get the file open in python.

I've tried in the node server.js:

```
var pythonOut;
const python = spawn('python', ['Scripts/convert_pdf.py', req.file]);
python.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
    pythonOut = data;
});
python.on('close', (code) => {
    console.log(`child process close all stdio with code ${code}`);
    console.log(pythonOut);
});
uploadToBlockchain(pythonOut);
```

Which if I read using sys.argv[1] in Python, gives me an [object Object] which I'm not sure how to open as a file to send to my transformer object. I've also tried sending req.file.buffer as an argument, but it simply sends a string of the buffer information rather than the actual bytes in the buffer.

Comment: What child process command have you tried?

Comment: @Alex028502 added in main post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your received `[object Object]` in your argv because the `spawn` accepts only an array of strings as arguments, while you passed an object(req.file).

Unfortunately i cannot help you with `python` code, but i can help with the `node` part and what you have to do:

1. You need to output in `convert_pdf.py` a base64 version of your results - just make sure your script runs ok and you have **only the encoded base64 output !** ( or skip this and read the 3rd point )
2. Prepare your `spawn` process:

```js
var pythonOut;
/**
 * Create a root function.
 * It's better to put an absolute path if you don't know the cwd(current working directory)
 * The arguments passed to root(x,y,z, ...n) will resolve relative to the __dirname (parent folder of the running node script file - i assume index.js - )
 */
const root = (...input) => require('path').resolve(__dirname, ...input);

const pythonScript = root("make/sure/the/path/is/valid", "Scripts/convert_pdf.py");
// If you're using Multer in memory use the line number 1
// If you're using Multer with an upload path use line number 2
const uploadedFile = req.file.buffer.toString('base64'); // 1
//const uploadedFile = req.file.destination; // 2 - this might be what you need, looking at your python code

console.log("pythonScript", pythonScript);
console.log("uploadedFile", uploadedFile);

// If you're running under windows and nodepad/defaultEditor opens by itself with the script contents, add the ".exe" extension to command e.g. python.exe
const command = 'python'; 

const {spawn} = require('child_process');
const python = spawn(command, [pythonScript, uploadedFile], {
  shell: true, // use the local shell
  env: {
    // Send node environment to the python process, it might need something from it, or not
    ...process.env
    // or add additional "key": "value" and send it to python env
  },
  // Here is the folder from where to run the python command, by default its process.cwd()
  // You don't need cwd now since pythonScript and uploadedFile have absolute paths
  // Set this correctly if you're using relative paths in your command arguments.
  // cwd: root("path/to/", "Scripts", "folder")
});

let storeDataChunks = [];

// I'm removing the new lines from the shell and storing the rows in storeDataChunks
const output = (data) => {
  let str = data.toString().split(/(\r\n|\n)+/).filter(i => i.trim().length);
  storeDataChunks = storeDataChunks.concat(str);
};
python.stdout.on('data', output);
python.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
  console.log('[errors from python]', data.toString());
});
python.on('close', (code) => {
  console.log(`child process close all stdio with code ${code}`);
  let pythonOut = storeDataChunks.join(''); // this will be the base64 string sent from python
  
  // Important: if you plan on sending a whole file such as "images/media with headers" from python do not use .toString() on the buffer.
  let decode = Buffer.from(pythonOut, 'base64').toString(); //decode base64
  decode = JSON.parse(decode); // You don't need this line if it's not an object
  console.log(decode);

  // Run here your upload function when the process is done.
  uploadToBlockchain(decode);
});
```

3. As a test print the python code from below in `convert_pdf.py`, it was generated in the browser console:

`browser: btoa(JSON.stringify(["hello\nworld", 2, {a: 3}, null]))`

`python:  print("WyJoZWxsb1xud29ybGQiLDIseyJhIjozfSxudWxsXQ==")`

Comment: Thanks a lot, just needed the b64 conversion of the file into convert_pdf.py to get it working, the code I tried before works with python just piping non b64 encoded back into node